# Trying to get BASH backup script to find an IP address based off known MAC address?

Tags: bash, awk, wifi, backup

I have a small BASH backup script that uses Rsync to grab a handful of computers on my LAN. It works very well for static devices using an Ethernet cable - trouble comes in for my even smaller number of Laptop users that have docks. Every once in a while they do not connect to the Dock & Ethernet cable/statically assigned address and end up on the WiFi with a DHCP assigned address. I already have a list of known statically assigned targets in a file that is parsed through to actually backed up. So I keep thinking I should fairly easily be able to create a second file with an nmap scan before each backup run with other code I found - something like:

```
    sudo nmap -n -sP 192.168.2.0/24 | awk '/Nmap scan report for/{printf $5;}/MAC Address:/{print " => "$3;}' | sort
```

which gives me a list of 192.168.2.101 => B4:FB:E4:FE:C6:6F for all found devices in the LAN. I just removed the | sort and send it to a file > found.devices instead.

So Now I have a list of found devices IP and MAC address - and I'd like to compare the two files and create a new target list with any changed IP addresses found (for those Laptop users that forgot to connect to the Dock and are now using DHCP). But I still want to keep my original targets file clean for the times that they do remember and also continue to get those other devices that are wired all the time while ignoring everything else on the LAN.

```
found.devices
192.168.2.190 => D4:XB:E4:FE:C6:6F
192.168.2.102 => B4:QB:Y4:FE:C6:6F
192.168.2.200 => B4:FB:P4:ZE:C6:6F
192.168.2.104 => B4:FB:E4:BE:P6:6F

known.targets
192.168.2.101 D4:XB:E4:FE:C6:6F domain source destination 
192.168.2.102 B4:QB:Y4:FE:C6:6F domain source destination 
192.168.2.103 B4:FB:P4:ZE:C6:6F domain source destination 
192.168.2.104 B4:FB:E4:BE:P6:6F domain source destination 

Should get a list or a file for the current back run to use of:
192.168.2.190 domain source destination
192.168.2.102 domain source destination
192.168.2.200 domain source destination
192.168.2.104 domain source destination
```

Currently my bash script just reads the file of known.targets one line at a time:

```
cat /known.targets | while read ip hostname source destination
     do 
     this mounts and backs up the data I want ...
```

I really like the current system, and have found it to be very reliable for my simple needs, just need to find some way to get those users that intermittently forget to dock. I expect its series of nested loops, but I cannot get my head to wrap around it - been away from actual coding for too long - Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. I'd also really like to get rid of the => and just use comma or space separated data but every time I mess with that awk statement - I end up shifting the data and getting an oddly placed CR somewhere I cannot figure it either!

Comment: Clearly i'm stupid - this solution is working fine, however - the MAC Address for a WIFI nic is different than the MAC address for an Ethernet nic and these days W10 and up have started randomizing MAC address for some stupid reason when hooking up to WiFi - making the entire endeavor no real help for the project. Guess those end users who forget to plug in will not be getting backed up! Thanks to all who responded and I did learn, so I guess there's that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this pure Bash code:

```
declare -A found_mac2ip
while read -r ip _ mac; do
    [[ -n $mac ]] && found_mac2ip[$mac]=$ip
done <'found.devices'

while read -r ip mac domain source destination; do
    ip=${found_mac2ip[$mac]-$ip}
    # ... DO BACKUP FOR $ip ...
done <'known.targets'
```

- It first sets up a Bash associative array mapping found mac address to ip addresses.
- It then loops through the `known.targets` file and for each mac address it uses the ip address from the `known.targets` file if the mac address is listed in it.  Otherwise it uses the ip address read from the `known.targets` file.

It's also possible to extract the "found" MAC and IP address information by getting it directly from the `nmap` output instead of from a `found.devices' file.  This alternative version of the code does that:

```
declare -A found_mac2ip
nmap_output=$(sudo nmap -n -sP 192.168.2.0/24)
while IFS=$' \t\n()' read -r f1 f2 f3 f4 f5 _; do
    [[ "$f1 $f2 $f3 $f4" == 'Nmap scan report for' ]] && ip=$f5
    [[ "$f1 $f2" == 'MAC Address:' ]] && found_mac2ip[$f3]=$ip
done <<<"$nmap_output"

while read -r ip mac domain source destination; do
    ip=${found_mac2ip[$mac]-$ip}
    # ... DO BACKUP FOR $ip ...
done <'known.targets'
```

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE:** per comment from OP, dropping assumption (and associated code) about keeping an IP address that shows up in `found.devices` but without a match in `known.targets` (ie, this cannot happen)

---

Assumptions:

- start with a list of IP/MAC addresses from `known.targets`
- if a MAC address also shows up in `found.devices` then the IP address from `found.devices` takes precendence

Adding a standalone entry to both files:

```
$ cat known.targets
192.168.2.101 D4:XB:E4:FE:C6:6F domain source destination
192.168.2.102 B4:QB:Y4:FE:C6:6F domain source destination
192.168.2.103 B4:FB:P4:ZE:C6:6F domain source destination
192.168.2.104 B4:FB:E4:BE:P6:6F domain source destination
111.111.111.111 AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF domain source destination

$ cat found.devices
192.168.2.190 => D4:XB:E4:FE:C6:6F
192.168.2.102 => B4:QB:Y4:FE:C6:6F
192.168.2.200 => B4:FB:P4:ZE:C6:6F
192.168.2.104 => B4:FB:E4:BE:P6:6F
222.222.222.222 => FF:EE:CC:BB:AA:11
```

One `awk` idea:

```
$ cat ip.awk
FNR==NR  { ip[$2]=$1; dsd[$2]=$3 FS $4 FS $5; next }
$3 in ip { ip[$3]=$1 }
END      { for (mac in ip) print ip[mac],dsd[mac] }
```

Running against our files:

```
$ awk -f ip.awk known.targets found.devices
192.168.2.200 domain source destination
192.168.2.190 domain source destination
192.168.2.104 domain source destination
111.111.111.111 domain source destination
192.168.2.102 domain source destination
```

Feeding this to a `while` loop:

```
while read ip hostname source destination
do
    echo "${ip} : ${hostname} : ${source} : ${destination}"
done < <(awk -f ip.awk known.targets found.devices)
```

This generates:

```
192.168.2.200 : domain : source : destination
192.168.2.190 : domain : source : destination
192.168.2.104 : domain : source : destination
111.111.111.111 : domain : source : destination
192.168.2.102 : domain : source : destination
```

Comment: Man awk just does not compute in my head! Y'all are wizards - This is doing what you stated - but it seems to be rebuilding the targets and removing some entries - for some targets, I need to get multiple sources - so were basically rebuilding/cleaning targets with new ip address only that have changed - aside from that cannot change anything else or we drop more than we pick up. I did not follow the NA bit - that too must remain the same as in the original targets - and yes - if they are not in targets then ignore it and strip out - tired the 2nd ip.awk.

Comment: @DAXQHome the `NA` entries have to do with example - `222.222.222.222` - exists in `found.devices` but not `known.targets` so there is nothing to use for the `domain`, `source` nor `destination` fields, hence `NA`; your comment that this shouldn't happen (MAC in `found.devices` but *not* in `known.targets`) means the inclusion of the `NA` code is not needed; other than that the script generates the same output you're expecting (besides a) different ordering of data and b) the inclusion of my example - `111.111.111.111` - which exists in `known.targets` but not in `found.devices`)

Comment: Humm - doesn't seem to be doing that for me worse - it seems to be mixing the domain source and targets as well as droping some targets - it is definitely dropping my multiple entries  e.g. ip address 192.168.2.190 has two entries one for source users and the second for source programX each going to their own targets - it almost looks like it shifted the targets up to a different address.

Comment: sorry, not following you; re: `192.168.2.190` ... this ip shows up *once* in the sample data and *once* in the expected output; are you saying that when you use these `awk` scripts, against the same sample data you've provided, that you something other than your expected results?

Comment: Well I definitely had some mac addresses misplaced, but I also definitely lost duplicate entries - will clean up and try again

Comment: So sorry to confuse - I am not using the sample data - in my real targets I have multiple entries for single targets. That and having some mac addresses incorrect is partially to blame for sure.

Comment: assuming you get the same results (as I do) with the provided sample data, but you get the 'wrong' results with your actual data, I'd suggest trying to tweak the `awk` code to work with your real data and if you can't get it to work then ask a new question, making sure to provide a more realistic set of data (eg, `multiple entries for single targets`?)  At this point  an update of the current sample data to include 'multiple entries' is bordering on changing the context of the question in which case it's typically cleaner to start with a new question

Comment: Ok I cleaned up my shiffted MAC address and got that resolved - the only thing its doing off now is if I have entry:
192.168.2.190 MyDomain Users MyDomain-Users
192.168.2.190 MyDomain FolderX MyDomain-FolderX 
in my targets file - the first entry disappears after I run through the second ip.awk you sent

Comment: yep, the current code does not take into consideration duplicate IPs and will in fact 'drop' duplicates; this (duplicates) wasn't demonstrated in the sample data hence wasn't addressed

Comment: Again very sorry - I should have had duplicates in my targets - did not think to do so. And you are correct - it is a key factor to consider and changes the question.

Comment: no prob; if you can't get a tweaked version of the current `awk` to work then ask a new question, provide more representative data and your attempts at tweaking the `awk` code; make sure the `awk` tag is added to the question ... there are several `awk`ers who'll be able to help out